# MemoryError openpyxl al convertir csv a xlsx

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

estoy tratandod de convertir un archivo csv a xlsx, pero al hacerlo me arroja error de memoria y ValueError: I/O operation on closed file. Estoy usando la librería openpyxl, agradezco cualquier ayuda.

este es mi código:

```
 wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
    ws = wb.active
    
    with open("D:/Q_DIARIO/ResCargueUnica"+archivo_dia+".csv", encoding='utf8') as f:
              reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter = '|')
              for row in reader:
                  ws.append(row)
    wb.save("ResCargueUnica"+archivo_dia+".xlsx")
```

log de error del cual entiendo que que presenta consumo de memoria al tratar de convertir el archivo a xlsx, ya que cambia cada | , mi archivo tiene 102321 filas. Subo parte del error ya que no me permitio subir todo.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python310-32\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 808, in _get_writer
    yield file.write
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python310-32\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 748, in write
    serialize(write, self._root, qnames, namespaces,
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python310-32\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 913, in _serialize_xml
    _serialize_xml(write, e, qnames, None,
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python310-32\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 913, in _serialize_xml
    _serialize_xml(write, e, qnames, None,
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python310-32\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 913, in _serialize_xml
    _serialize_xml(write, e, qnames, None,
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python310-32\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 907, in _serialize_xml
    write(" %s=\"%s\"" % (qnames[k], v))
MemoryError
```

Comment: Por favor, pon el mensaje de error completo en la pregunta

Comment: Es probable que el error se deba a que el csv es muy grande. Por lo que usar la forma convencional de crear un workbook en openpyxl gastaría muchisima memoria, ya que inevitablemente cargarías todo el archivo en memoria. Esta pagina de la documentación tiene infomación sobre el tema: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/optimized.html